# PostgresSQL: Select rows where a JSONB field contains all items in an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the database table below where tags are arrays stored as JSONB, how can I write an SQL query to only select ids that contain all tags value's in an array?

e.g only records `1` and `2` would be returned for the array `{"London", "Sydney"}`

```
 id |             tags                 
----+---------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"value": "Sydney"..}, {"value": "London"..}, {"value": "Munich"..}]
  2 | [{"value": "Sydney"..}, {"value": "London"..}]
  3 | [{"value": "London"..}]
  4 | [{"value": "Sydney"..}]
```

I managed to construct this query however it does not return an absolute match for ALL the items in the array which is what I'm after..

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(tags) tag 
    WHERE tag->>'value' IN ('London', 'Sydney')
)
```

Comment: What if you have a row with `[{"value": "Sydney"}, {"value": "London"}, {"value": "Munich"}]` should that also be returned?

Comment: Yes, that can also be returned! just edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [contains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) operator `@>` with a JSON array:

```
select * 
from the_table
where tags @> '[{"value": "London"}, {"value": "Sydney"}]'
```

Or you can use a JSON path expression

```
select * 
from the_table
where jsonb_path_query_array(tags, '$[*].value') ?& array['London', 'Sydney']
```